# How can I override the width of container to 1440px and make the columns in the same time Responsive using Bootstrap 4 and Scss

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, responsive-design, grid

How can I override the width of container to 1440px and make the columns in the same time responsive. I am using Bootstrap 4 and SCSS.

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- Container 1440px-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="first"></div><!-- Section 825px-->
        <div class="second"></div><!-- Section 615px-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: apply your own css

Comment: try writing css such as : ```.container{width:1440px;}  .first{width:825px;} .second{width:615px};```

Answer (score 0):

The media query will adjust the width of your container to 1440px only on screens larger than 1200px (or whatever width you want). It will maintain the responsiveness of your website too!

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1440px;
  }
}
```